# Javascript regexp lets undesirable characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regExp in my project but some how I'm getting some undesirable characters

my RegExp looks like this:

```
new RegExp("[א-ת,A-z,',','(',')','.','-',''']");
```

which supposed to avoid characters like \ or []

but let my use one and more from (,),-,alphabets etc.

Unfortunately it doesnt happen

Which pattren includes both desirable and undesirable characters??

thanks for your help

Comment: Your pattern makes no sense. Can you elaborate your expectations of your RegExp?

Comment: /\w/g is a general regexp for matching non alphanumerics.  But you really need to post more information about your test cases.  There are a lot of variations that you gloss over with "like...etc.".

Comment: Do you want to match a single character anywhere in the string?  Or do you want to test that the string consists only of those characters?

Answer (score 3):

Well your regular expression just says to match **one** "good" character (and incorrectly at that).

I think something closer to this would be what you want, though I'm not sure about the higher-page UTC characters:

```
var regexp = /^[א-תA-Za-z,()\-']*$/;
```

If the alefbet part doesn't work (it looks backwards to me, but I guess that's kind of a conundrum :-), try:

```
var regexp = /^[\u05DA-\05EAA-Za-z,()\-']*$/;
```

Might be good to tack an "i" (ignore case) modifier on the end too:

```
var regexp = /^[\u05DA-\05EAA-Za-z,()\-']*$/i;
```

This also does not handler the various diacritical marks; I don't know if you need those matched or not.

Comment: If you move the `-` to the beginning of the character class, it won't need to be escaped.

Comment: Consider changing `*` to `+` so that this regex won't match the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need all those single quotes and commas.  Second, you want `A-Za-z`, not.`A-z`.  The latter includes ASCII characters between "Z" and "a".

```
var re = new RegExp("[א-תA-Za-z,()\.'\s-]");
```

Comment: FYI: this regex will only match 1 character. Is that the intention?

Comment: How can I add whitespace to this regExp?

Comment: Add a `\s` to the regular expression.  `\s` matches any Unicode whitespace character (there's a lot of them!).  I have updated the answer with this change.  You might want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for a good explanation of regular expressions in JavaScript.

Comment: @Asaph: If you look closely at the regex in the question, you'll see that the first 'quoted' character is a comma, so I think it belongs there.

Comment: @Alan Moore: My comment was in reference to this answer, not the question. Unfortunately, Annabelle changed her answer completely after I left my comment. The original text of Annabelle's answer (which can be seen in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8037947/revisions)) was '`Change A-z to A-Z,a-z. The former includes ASCII characters between "Z" and "a"`'. My comment applies to that.

Comment: @Asaph: Ah, I see now!  Yes, that was at least ambiguous, if not plain wrong.